# how to break and continue after every iteration using for loop in swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, break

I am using the following code to break and continue in for loop. I want to break and continue the for loop after every iteration. For example when i=0 loop complete the iteration and and break the loop and again continue with i=1 and complete the iteration and break and then continue the iteration with i=2 so on.

```
outer: for i in 0..<micSources.count {

    if let cell = self.micTestFaliureTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? MicFaliureTableViewCell {
        //let micLocation = cell.micFaliureTestview.micLocation

        //let indexpath = micTestFaliureTableView.indexPath(for: cell)


        if !cell.micFaliureTestview.success {
            cell.micFaliureTestview.startRecording()
            break outer
        }

    }
    continue outer
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Are you testing N microphone inputs and if they don't "success" you call a "startRecording()" ?

Comment: yes bro you are right

Comment: Iterating over tableview cells is almost always the wrong thing to do; you should iterate over your table data source array.  You don't need a `continue outer` - the loop will just continue with the next iteration when it hits the close `}`

Comment: the problem is that when for example two microphone fail for loop start the execution for those mics together, otherwise for one microphone fail case it is working fine and giving problem when two mics fails

Comment: So you probably don't need the `break` or `continue` statements.

Comment: when i use this inside the loop...
if !cell.micFaliureTestview.success {
                    cell.micFaliureTestview.startRecording()
                }
all fail mics start together but i want with sequence

Comment: If you want to update the UI over time, you will need to use a `Timer` rather than a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test and display microphone status in a tableView,
I recommend you call a `updateData()` function in `viewDidLoad()` of your viewController.

```
var microphoneStatus: [Bool]?
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // test the microphone status only once, 
    // when the view is loaded for the first time.
    updateData()
}

private func updateData() {
    for microphoneSource in micSources {
        let isMicrophoneRunning = microphoneSource.success
        microphoneStatus.append(isMicrophoneRunning)
        if !isMicrophoneRunning { startMicrophone }
    }
}
```

And then, use the tableview data source delegate to feed your tableview.
And use the microphoneStatus array to show their status.

You can even create an array of `struct` instead of a `[Bool]` and that struct will contain the name of the input, it's number and it's status.
Then you can use this array of struct to simply display your data in the tableView.

It seems your problem is another problem:

> when i use this inside the loop... if !cell.micFaliureTestview.success
>   { cell.micFaliureTestview.startRecording() } all fail mics start
>   together but i want with sequence – Umair Shams

I recommend looking into the `startRecording()` function signature and see if there is a handler that is called only once the startRecording is finished.
Then you can chain the `startRecording()` calls properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 0..<micSources.count {
    // use custom class for your data array and control over that list, then reload/update your tableview.
    if let cell = self.micTestFaliureTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) as? MicFaliureTableViewCell {
        if !cell.micFaliureTestview.success {
            cell.micFaliureTestview.startRecording()
        }
    }
}
```